# Unitary matrix that diagonalizes real symmetric matrix

Tags: vector-spaces

I am confused by the following statement from a book:

> Since a symmetric matrix is Hermitian, it can be diagonalized by a
>   unitary matrix. But since the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are
>   real, the diagonalizing unitary matrix is in fact real orthogonal.
>   However, the eigenvalues of a real orthogonal matrix will, in general,
>   be complex and therefore the unitary matrix that diagonalizes it
>   cannot usually be chosen to be real orthogonal.

So it seems to suggest that the nature of eigenvalues for real normal matrix determine whether the unitary matrix that diagonalizes is a real orthogonal or not.

Why is that?

Clearly, hermitian matrix always have real eigenvalues, but this doesn't imply that a matrix that diagonalizes is a real orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a real matrix and $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue, then the equation
$$
(A - \lambda I)x = 0
$$
will have a real vector $x$ as a solution.  That is, $A$ will have real eigenvectors.  It follows that if $A$ has an orthonormal eigen-basis, it must have a real orthonormal eigenbasis.

Comment: very clear, thank you.